# Create item in list 2 from list 1 SharePoint Designer 2013 using "Create item in"

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm creating a list of employee information with name, title, etc. I want that basic ID information to be inserted into another list when my workflow runs (just name, title, email). When I "create item in" I only get the ability to create a variable as a GUID. How can I turn that GUID into the names of the values (person's actual name, title, email address). I thought I had figured out a way but the workflow suspended and I always would get the "The lookup that you defined is not guaranteed to return single value. If more than value is returned only the firs value will be used".

I can get it to insert ONE item only, and it's whichever item is first. I moved "Title" to the top and it ignores the next item and only enters the title of Manager:

[image]

[image]

and I noticed the workflow still suspends with the error:

Resume this workflow
 RequestorId: 46fad260-144a-f347-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.FormatException: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx). at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String failureArgumentName, Exception innerException) at System.Guid.TryParseGuidWithNoStyle(String guidString, GuidResult& result) at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult& result) at System.Guid.Parse(String input) at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation) Exception from activity ParseGuid Assign Insert Name Insert Item Sequence Flowchart Sequence Irvine Onboarding.WorkflowXaml_ec3d67f9_8dc6_47f2_98ea_a28ad723f2cc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in seeing that the `Create Item in` action only outputs a Guid type variable as it references the new list item (in your target list (Irvine- First Day).  You can then use this Guid variable to reference the list item to make updates to the new item in the **target** list using the `Update item in` action.  To do this, you select the target list, specify the fields to be updated with the appropriate values then in the 'Find the List Item' section, you enter `Field` of GUID and `Value` of 'Variable:IrvTitle' using the data in your example.

However, if you have all the required data in the current list at the stage in the WF you create the list item, why not add the additional fields and data at the same time (i.e. in the 'Create Item' action).  You are able to add multiple field values at the same time and then do not need to worry about the output variable unless you then later need to refer to the new item to make further updates, using the method I described above.

Comment: Perfect! This makes so much more sense-- thanks a million.

Comment: I'm having an issue doing this same process but in 2010. Any chance you could take a look? GUID is not an option. Only List Item ID http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/178367/create-item-in-list-2-from-list-1-sharepoint-designer-2010-using-create-item-in

Answer (score 0):

follow this step
 you have two SharePoint lists named List1 and List2. List1 has one column named Title, and List2 has 2 columns named Column1 and Column2.

In SharePoint Designer 2013, create a new SharePoint workflow and associate it with the List1 SharePoint list.
Add a Create List Item action to the workflow.
Click this list in the workflow action.
On the Create New List Item dialog box, select List2 from the List drop-down list box.
Select Column1 in the list of fields, and then click Modify.
On the Value Assignment dialog box, click the second button behind the To this value text box.
On the Lookup for Single line of text dialog box, leave Current Item selected, select Title from the Field from source drop-down list box, and click OK.
On the Value Assignment dialog box, click OK.
On the Create New List Item dialog box, click OK.
like add  other fields also.

in both list  try to have same column name without any case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Dear You can use the following
Create item in 'Second List' (Output to Variable: create )
[image]